# WARNING DefaultFilterChainValidator.checkLoginPageIsntProtected Anonymous access to the login page doesn't appear to be enabled

Tags: spring, spring-security, redirect-loop

I am creating a plain `Login form` for spring security authentication:

Here is `security-config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login2.xhtml" access="hasRole('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login2.xhtml"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="sajjad" authorities="ROLE_USER" password="abcdef"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I want to authenticate all requests of application to be `user`

Here is in `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/security-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- SPRING SECURITY RELATED CONFIG-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- JSF Servlet is defined to container -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Mapping with servlet and url for the http requests. -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But problem is when i request any page, the browser show this error:

(The url is `http://localhost:8080/login2.xhtml`)

[image]

`Tomcat Catalina Log`

```
WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(18)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.checkLoginPageIsntProtected Anonymous access to the login page doesn't appear to be enabled.
This is almost certainly an error. Please check your configuration allows unauthenticated access to the configured login page.

(Simulated access was rejected: 
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you first access login; the user doesnt have any role(since he isnt logged in spring security yet) the login page should not restricted by role; it should be available to all user.

Comment: I added     `<security:intercept-url pattern="/login2.xhtml" access="hasRole('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')"/>`

Comment: you can also use <http pattern="/login2.xhtml" security="none" />

Comment: this did not work for me. When i removed access="hasRole('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')", csrf_token is null so I was getting 403 HTTP error